# How to pass a jquery script in the flashdata of codeigniter to trigger/show a bootstrap modal?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

the situation is, I want to show the modal once the form submission is successful.
what i currently do is, after I submit and the form was submitted successfully, I redirect to the same input page. Now the question is, is it possible to set the flash data and pass a jquery script to toggle the modal upon redirection ? here's how i set it in the controller function after the submission was successful.

```
$js = "<script>$('#mymodal').modal('show');</script>";
$this->session->set_flashdata('js',$js);
```

then on the view file , I placed a checker at the top so that I will get triggered upon redirection to it.

```
if($this->session->flashdata('js')){
   echo $this->session->flashdata('js');
}
```

but unfortunately, the modal didn't get triggered to popup at all.. show how ?

Comment: Did you put second code block into `$(document).on(ready(){/** here */})`?

Comment: you mean in the view file ? i should echo out the flashdata inside that snippet of yours?

Comment: Yes. PHP variables come first so you need to be sure it won't echo before jQuery and bootstrap js code loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with this way..

From coontroller ... You send a simple flash message like..

```
$js = "1";
$this->session->set_flashdata('js',$js);
```

And In View,

```
 <?php 
    if(isset($this->session->flashdata('js')) && $this->session->flashdata('js')=="1"){
    ?>
       <script>$('#mymodal').modal('show');</script>
    <?php } ?>
```

It will be working fine, Enjoy the code.